# eclipse gcov integration doesn't find static libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcov

I have an eclipse workspace with two projects. The first is a static library written in C++ and the second is a collection of unit tests written in C++ using catch.hpp.

I am trying to use the eclipse plugin to evaluate the code coverage that the second project offers the first, however, whenever I run the unit testing project, it refuses to report on code coverage for the static library.

I do get code coverage on the test project which is not very useful.

Is there a configuration option to eclipse that will cause the code coverage to work?